# How to provide an all-trusting SslProvider in netty?

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, netty, spring-webflux

I want to create a netty `HttpClient` configuration that trusts all SSL certificates:

```
httpClient.secure(spec -> {
    spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE));
})
```

Problem: `sslContext()` is marked with `@Deprecated` as follows:

> as of 1.0.6. Prefer sslContext(SslProvider.ProtocolSslContextSpec),
> where the default configuration is applied before any other custom
> configuration. This method will be removed in version 1.2.0.

Question: how can I refactor the statement above to the non-deprecated version?

Comment: These classes are not pure netty. Please clarify what exact library you are using

Comment: I'm using `spring-boot` and `spring-webflux`.

Answer (score 3):

Because the method accepting an `SslContext` is not deprecated, you just have to add call to `build()`. The code should look as follows:

```
httpClient.secure(spec -> {
    spec.sslContext(SslContextBuilder
            .forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE)
            .build());
})
```